# Oracle string replacement using lookup tables

Tags: oracle10g

Can someone please help me with this issue?
I have my client address stored in a table (table `CT`) as a string which could have some abbreviated data. Example: `123 RD`. I have another look up table (table `LK`) which contains possible street names for the abbreviations. `RD = ROAD`.
I would like to create a new table which has the complete address for this string.

Input:

```
table CT:

Add1     Add2   Add3
------------------------
123 RD   APT 2  BLDG 1
test DR  null   null
main RD  null   BLDG2


table LK:

abbreviation      completestreet
----------------------------------
RD                road
APT               apartment
BLDG              building
DR                drive
```

I would like to join these two tables to achieve the following:

```
123 ROAD      APARTMENT 2    BUILDING 1
test DRIVE    null           null
main ROAD     null           BUILDING 2
```

Comment: How do you know to add a space after replacing `BLDG` in `BLDG2` but not after replacing the same string in `BLDG 1`?  What happens if you have something like '123 3rd Street'?  There is an `RD` there but it would not make sense in context to replace it.  But we can't simply say "only replace whole words separated by spaces" without failing to modify the `BLDG2` string.  And what if one of the abbreviations appears in another word?

Comment: different operators enter data differently and there could be space on one of them but not all. We are ready to accept a small variance in the final solution. Our main criteria is to replace the abbreviation value followed by space. so to replace 123 RD but not 123 3rd street.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to find a solution that uses `regexp_replace` together with the *regexp word boundaries* `^|` and `|$`:

```
with ct as (
  select '123 RD'          add1, 'APT 2' add2, 'BLDG 1' add3 from dual union all
  select '123 3RD street'  add1, 'APT 2' add2, 'BLDG 1' add3 from dual union all
  select 'test DR'         add1, ''      add2, ''       add3 from dual union all
  select 'main RD'         add1, ''      add2, 'BLDG2'  add3 from dual
),
lk as (
  select 'RD'    abbreviation, 'road'       completestreet from dual union all
  select 'APT'   abbreviation, 'apartment'  completestreet from dual union all
  select 'BLDG'  abbreviation, 'building'   completestreet from dual union all
  select 'DR'    abbreviation, 'drive'      completestreet from dual
),
recursion (add1, add2, add3, l) as (
  select add1, add2, add3, 1 l from ct union all
  select regexp_replace(add1, '(^| )' ||abbreviation || '( |$)', '\1' || completestreet || '\2'),
         regexp_replace(add2, '(^| )' ||abbreviation || '( |$)', '\1' || completestreet || '\2'),
         regexp_replace(add3, '(^| )' ||abbreviation || '( |$)', '\1' || completestreet || '\2'),
         l+1
    from recursion join (
            select 
               row_number() over (order by abbreviation) r, 
               abbreviation, 
               completestreet 
             from lk
         ) lk
         on l=r
)
select substrb(add1, 1, 30),
       substrb(add2, 1, 30),
       substrb(add3, 1, 30)
  from recursion
 where l=(select count(*)+1 from lk);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I am getting an invalid SQL error in Oracle 10g

Comment: Yes, that's for 11g. I obviously missed that you tagged the question `oracle10g`